# Eloquent collections with a relation of another relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I have Post eloquent related with PostCategory and my collection is good.

```
class Post extends Model
{

    public function post_categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PostCategory::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function detail($slug_category, $slug)
    {
       $detail = Post::with('post_categories')
           ->whereHas('post_categories', function ($query) use ($slug_category){
            $query->where('category_slug', $slug_category);
         })->where('slug', $slug)
         ->first();
        return($detail);
    }

}
```

I have this another class 'Players' where i need to have a collection with all user's posts with PostCategory category relation.

```
class Players extends Model
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }


    public function detail($slug_category, $slug_name)
    {

        $detail = Player::with('posts')
                        ->whereHas('players_info', function ($query) use ($slug_name){
                            $query->where('slug', $slug_name);
                        })
                        ->whereHas('player_categories', function ($query) use ($slug_category){
                            $query->where('category_slug', $slug_category);
                        })->first();

        return($detail);

    }

}
```

I read something about "belongsToMany" and "withPivot", but I'm still confused for correct way.

What can I do to resolve this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved just with this.

```
return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->with('post_categories');
```

Comment: with does not define any relation, it just loads a relation on your result.

You ussualy could lazy access it with `$player->posts()->first()->post_categories`